# @Around advice not being triggered

Tags: java, aspectj

In my Java application, I want to intercept calls to commands. Every command class has a name that ends with `Command` and a method `public void run(...)` invoked to execute the command.

I tried `@Around("execution(void *.*Command.run(..))")` and various variations, but I can't get it to trigger.

I have other pointcuts in my application that work just fine, so it's not an AspectJ configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have package names like `org.company.application.domain` rather than just `something`. Your pointcut assumes the latter, though. In order to match against classes no matter how deep their subpackage is nested, you need to use the double dot notation `..`:

```java
@Around("execution(void *..*Command.run(..))")
```